# CLK signal on DAT0 line on SD protocol?

Tags: clock, sd, protocol

I'm facing some problems in the initialization stage of the SD protocol on a custom board, specifically when sending the `ACMD51` command and reading the Status Card register on the `DAT0` line. I've noticed that, when the command fails, I see a duplicated `CLK` signal on the `DAT0` line.
The picture below shows the `CMD` line(magenta), `DAT0` line(yellow) and CLK(cyan). The last pulse before the B cursor is the end bit of the `ACMD51` command. As can be seen, the `DAT0` line replicates the `CLK` while the command is transferring and even after the command is issued (just for one pulse).

[image: screenshot]

I've looked in the specs and, from what I understood, `DAT` lines should be HIGH when there's no data for transferring or LOW for signaling busy, but I don't get what could be the meaning of that duplicated `CLK`, apparently sent by the card itself. Maybe I've missed some point on the specs. What could cause that oscillation on the `DAT` line?

Comment: Do you mean magenta when you say cyan and do you mean cyan when you say blue?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I'll correct it. Thanks :)